# Best way to display output of pattern search on text files?

Tags: c++, regex, file-io

first question here!

I'm writing a grep type program for Windows, just for fun (using Mingw). It works well for text files where lines are terminated by '\n'. I'm using fstream::getline() for this.

But I also need to be able to search files containing just a giant block of text with no line numbers. fstream::getline() fails here. Is there any function to read N characters into a buffer from such a file?

Also, what's the best way to tell the user where the match was found in such a file?

Comment: Traditional `grep` operating on a file containing only one line would simply output the entire line. If you want to do something else, about all you can do is tell the user how many characters in it was. The problem is, you have to make an arbitrary decisions about when you stop considering it a single-line file, where you'd output the whole line, and start considering it a huge block.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll indicate the number of characters from start of file for unformatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[istream::read()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/) will read an arbitrary number of characters from an istream.

As for where in the file it was found, a line number and character offset might be a good way to go.